# Calibrating irregularly sampled Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I would like to recover the parameters of a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process from observations that are *irregularly* spaced. Estimation via linear regression and maximum likelihood is demonstrated [here](http://www.sitmo.com/article/calibrating-the-ornstein-uhlenbeck-model/) for the case where the observations arrive at regularly spaced intervals. What would be the solution for irregularly sampled data?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done this myself, but my first instinct would be to see if we can express OU process as a state space model. These can be estimated on uneven intervals, missing data etc.

[Here's the paper](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~thomanen/Geo599/Schwartz.pdf) which estimates OU process with a Kalman filter.